# Quickly update Chrome App window after screen is back on

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Google chrome app on Windows 7 that is a simple clock/alarm. The javascript code calls the updateClock() function (using a timer) every one minute to render the new clock value (2:01pm >> 2:02pm >> 2:03pm >> etc) and play an .mp3 file when the alarm is due.

If I do not use the PC for a long time, the screen goes off. Still, I know that the updateClock() function is being called every minute since the alarm sounds at the proper time.

However, if I bring the screen back on (by moving the mouse or pressing the keyboard), my app shows the clock value when the screen went off (say 2:01pm), while the current time might be 3:30pm. If I hover the mouse over the app or wait for another minute, the app updates to the proper time (3:30pm).

It seems that Google chrome stops rendering the HTML page when the screen is off and does not do a quick rendering when the screen is back on again. Is there a javascript or chrome API workaround to quickly update the clock when the screen is on again?

I tried the chrome API:

`chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(updateClock);`

and the javascript:

`window.addEventListener("pageshow", updateClock, false);`

but none helped.

Please note that I would rather not add a timer that fires every second to update the clock as I want to minimize the required resources for my app.

**Edit:** Here is the sample program I am working with:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span id="hhDisplay" ></span>:<span id="mmDisplay" ></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
function updateClock() {
var date = new Date();
hhDisplay.innerHTML = date.getHours();
mmDisplay.innerHTML = date.getMinutes();

var minuteOffset = ((60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000) - date.getMilliseconds();

if (minuteOffset > 0)
    setTimeout(updateClock, minuteOffset);
else
    updateClock();
}

window.onload = function() {
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(function(newstate) { updateClock(); });
updateClock();
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
chrome.app.window.create("index.html",
{ id: "TestClock", minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300 }); });
```

manifest.json

```
{ "name": "Clock Test", "version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"minimum_chrome_version": "18",
"app": { "background": {  "scripts": ["background.js"] } },
"permissions": ["idle"] }
```

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this using a simple app that updates dom occasionally and manually locking the screen (linux, win8). chrome.idle appears to work for me, also. I don't think pageshow is relevant, at least from reading specification, as it's related to navigation. Try reducing down to the simplest app that updates body.innerText on an interval with a window that you leave up. If it is still an issue file a bug at crbug.com.

Comment: Thanks. I reported this as issue# 244252, as I can easily reproduce it. Could you please try the sample program I am using (see Edit in the Question)? Also please try to leave the screen off for a few minutes. Finally, if you don't mind, which chrome version are you using? I am using Chrome version 24.0.1312.56 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener
```

should work, and does on Mac and Linux at least. Your filed [issue 244252](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244252) will track it not working on Windows.

For now, you can workaround the issue by updating just moments after the idle state changes, e.g. with

```
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(function() { setTimeout(updateClock, 100); });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested workaround did not work for me on Windows. The chrome.idle.onStateChanged does not fire when the screen is back on. Maybe it only fires after the PC comes out of sleep; not when the screen is off/on (while the PC is still awake)! Thanks for following up on the bug report, though.

Comment: It does fire for me on win8 coming out of monitor off. It's a bug otherwise. Note, my screen locks and prompts for password. Is yours just powering off and on with no lock? I've filed https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246088 for onStateChanged not firing.

Comment: Yes. On my system, the screen powers off then on without any locks. If it helps, I use Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit with no service packs installed. I agree that onStateChanged not firing is a bug.

Comment: I upgraded from Chrome 24.0 to Chrome 27.0 and Voila! The workaround `chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(function() { setTimeout(updateClock, 100); });` started producing correct results (Win 7 64-bit). Thanks!